# A div, entire width of page without breaking flow

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to write a div which has a width of 100% (the yellow-ish ones in the pic below), without breaking the flow of the document?

[image]

Comment: A `div` element by default expands to take all the width of its containing `div`. Be careful with margins and padding, as this may throw off the spacing.

Comment: The "container" of the page is set at 960px wide, so yes, the `div` will inherit the parent `div`s width; thus making it 960px wide. But I need 1 particular `div` to extend past this width, without breaking flow.

Comment: .JamesKentDIV{ margin-left:100%; float:left; display:inline; }

Comment: Then you need to reformat your HTML. There is no reason this is not possible by nesting div elements with different widths. Anything else would probably be hacky.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: I would love nothing more to reformat the entire site, but due to time limitations it's just not possible, this time.

Comment: @JamesKent See my answer. It is relatively simple as long as your `div` elements are in the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="big">
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="small">
       //content
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.big
{
    background-color:#whatever;
}

.small
{
     width:75%;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div {position:absolute;}
```

or
    div {postion:fixed;}
will remove it from the document flow, but you may have to specify the left and top to put it where you want it once you remove it, depending on which one you use.

Answer (score 1):

A div will automatically take up the whole width of it's parent (`<body>` in this case). If you insert

```
style="clear:both"
```

Into the div you'd like to stretch, it will ensure that it is not alongside any other elements (following the normal flow of the page) hence it will stretch the width of the body.